# Libre 2D game engine with Tiled support

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, open-source, game-development

I'm looking for a 2D game engine with (preferably built-in) support for the [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) map editor. It should run on at least Linux and Windows, with macOS and other platforms (such as mobile) as an added bonus.

It should have at least basic collision support, although a full physics engine would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up going with [LÖVE](http://love2d.org/) and [STI](https://github.com/Karai17/Simple-Tiled-Implementation), a Tiled map loader for LÖVE.

While LÖVE provides bindings to Box2D, allowing for advanced physics simulation, I've ended up using bump.lua (can be found on Github), as it is a lot simpler and provides everything I need for now. STI integrates very well with both LÖVE's built-in physics engine and bump.lua, making things such as collision layers incredibly simple to set up.

Answer (score 0):

[Unity3D](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/) provides a linux support since 2015 and its fully functional.

You can use [Tiled2Unity](http://www.seanba.com/tiled2unity) to import any tiled map direct to unity.

It as 2D support and every feature you need,with 27 build platform support,you will never be disappointed, i myself use it for commercial use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but Unity is proprietary, while I asked for a [freely licensed](https://www.fsf.org/about/what-is-free-software) platform.

Comment: You said nothing about license issue on your question,you found what you want anyway.

Comment: It was in the title, and I've now added a tag, but you are correct, I didn't specify it in the body of my question.